# Can Bochs run OS X as a guest OS?

Tags: macos, emulation, bochs

Simple question: Will OS X ([Hackintosh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSx86), [Unibeast](http://www.tonymacx86.com/374-unibeast-install-os-x-mavericks-any-supported-intel-based-pc.html) configured to run on a "generic PC platform") work on the Bochs x86 PC emulator?

Regardless of terms or rules, does it work? Can anyone confirm it?

Comment: Regardless of installing in Bochs or on a physical machine it's the same 2 issues that you'll have to overcome: OSX only includes driver support for Apple computers, and during the installation the installer will check for Apple's modified EFI to verify you are installing on a legit Apple computer. Given that Bochs is essentially just an x86 equivalent of PearPC I'd say that if you can overcome the afformentioned issues you should be able to run OSX on it. It would be beyond slow though.

Answer (score 2):

I've successfully run OS X in emulators such as Virtualbox (was bloody slow though) and VMWare workstation, so I'd say yes, however there are many problems that you need to take care, such as finding and installing "kexts" (equivalent of device drivers) to make the virtual hardware work correctly so it's hard but not impossible.

However, it seems that running OS X in Virtualbox or VMware is more popular so you'll get much more help and how-to guides for those platforms, so why not run it in one of these virtual machines instead ?

Comment: VirtualBox isn't an x86 emulator though...